# Bond angle and bond lengths in Arginine

Tags: lewis-structure

[image]

Based on the Lewis structure of arginine, the terminal primary amine attached to the guanidine group seems to be $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridized and trigonal pyramidal. Also, in [quantum mechanical computations](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/299499560_Optical_Dielectric_Ferroelectric_studies_on_amino_acids_doped_TGS_single_crystals), it is shown  that all carbon-nitrogen bonds in the guanidine group are different lengths.

However, in the 3d structure below, the entire guanidine group is planar, indicating an sp2 hybridization. Why is $\ce{N}$ $\mathrm{sp^2}$ and not $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridized? Why is the guanidine group planar? Why are all the bond lengths different if all the $\ce{N}$ atoms are $\mathrm{sp^2}$?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered resonance?

Comment: The paper you linked with the reference to quantum mechanical calculations appears to be instead a description of a crystal structure doped with arginine. In that structure the C-N bonds are identical within error, and the guanidino group is described as planar, so all sp2 hybridized.

Comment: @Andrew, what do you mean "All C-N bonds are identical within error"?

Comment: In the paper you linked, the bond lengths are given as 1.351, 1.340 and 1.322. That’s identical as far as I’m concerned. Compare to the C-N bond of the primary amine at 1.48. Clearly a difference in bond order.

Comment: Atoms cannot be hybridised, only orbitals can. Therefore it is incorrect to state N is sp² hybridised, even though it is used in that way (too) often. Consider it lab jargon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L-arginine is the most basic amino acid since it carries guanidyl group in addition to the $\alpha$-amino group. The arginine molecule is a zwitterion with the guanidyl group, rather than the primary $\alpha$-amino group, accepting extra proton from carboxylic acid group (Ref.1). Protonated or not, when consider guanidine as a molecule, there shouldn't be any $\mathrm{sp^3}$ nitrogen in the molecule because it is resonance-stabilized molecule. As a guanidyl group, this principle stays the same and it stays flat. There are few excellent answers to similar question you could find in [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/protonation-of-guanidine). In one answer it states that:

> Guanidine is isolobal to urea, where the carbonyl oxygen has been replaced by an imine $\ce{NH}$. However, in principle it is still the same flat, resonance-stabilised molecule. The main difference is that there is no ‘preferred’ site for the double bond — it could point towards any of the three nitrogens in theory; you could say the diamide resonance is enhanced (Author: Jan).

And, accepted answer showed following diagram to depict the concept of resonance stabilization (Author: Ron):

[image: Guanidine reseonance]

Further, I'll attached recent crystal structure of L-arginine, which shows clear equivalent three nitrogen atoms with hydrohen bonding network (Ref.2):

[image: Arginine Crystal]

> Two planes characterize the arginine molecule: one through the acid group and the other through the extended side chain, which contains the guanidyl group. The dihedral angle between these two planes is $74^\circ$ (Ref.1).

---

**References:**

1. I. L. Karle, J. Karle, “An application of the symbolic addition method to the structure of L-arginine dehydrate,” *Acta Cryst.* **1964**, *17*, 835–841 (https://doi.org/10.1107/S0365110X64002250).
2. Emilie Courvoisier, P. Andrew Williams, Gin K. Lim, Colan E. Hughes,  Kenneth D. M. Harris, “The crystal structure of L-arginine,” *Chem. Commun.* **2012**, *48*, 2761–2763 (DOI: 10.1039/C2CC17203H).

Comment: So the nitrogens in the guanidine group are all sp2 and planar, correct?

Comment: Also, are all the nitrogen bond lengths the same in the guanidine group, or no?

Comment: @DrPepper: See Andrew's comments to your question.

Comment: That answer by Ron, and especially the image, is terrible. Apart from some hand waving and a much too literal use of hybridisation, there is not much more to it. I doubt there is a large enough barrier (if at all) for the protonation step to be able to identify kinetics versus thermodynamics.

Comment: @Mithoron: To your information, I didn't copy and paste and pretend it's my answer.  Since you didn't know me, search google my name and find who I am. I'm a genuine researcher and do not disrespect me. You have no rights to order me.

Comment: Wow, seems I need to write who know how much for anyone to understand... You cited Jan's answer - this is *not* a good practice. One could "cite" whole answer this way...  and  our site isn't a source for itself (Wikipedia learned it ages ago). One should write as much as possible with own words, etc. etc.

Comment: @Mithoron: If you know so much, why you don't give your own answer and mind your own business. There are moderators to do these kind of critical work.